# Cannot print out the latest results of table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
NAMES:
Fname   |  stime  |  etime   |  Ver   |   Rslt
x            4         5        1.01     Pass
x            8        10        1.01     Fail
x            6         7        1.02     Pass
y            4         8        1.01     Fail
y            9        10        1.01     Fail 
y           11        12        1.01     Pass
y           10        14        1.02     Fail
m            1         2        1.01     Fail
m            4         6        1.01     Fail
```

The result I am trying to output is:

```
x            8        10        1.01     Fail
x            6         7        1.02     Pass
y           11        12        1.01     Pass
y           10        14        1.02     Fail
m            4         6        1.01     Fail
```

What the result means:
Fnames are an example of tests that are run. Each test was run on different platforms of software (The version numbers) Some tests were run on the same platform twice: It passed the first time and failed the second time or vice versa. My required output is basically the latest result of each case for each version. So basically the results above are all unique by their combination of Fname and Ver(sion), and they are selected by the latest etime from the unique group.

The query I have so far is:

```
select Fname,stime,max(etime),ver,Rslt from NAMES group by Fname,Rslt;
```

This however, does not give me the required output.
The output I get is (wrong):

```
x            4        10        1.01     Fail
x            6         7        1.02     Pass
y            4        12        1.01     Pass
y           10        14        1.02     Fail
m            1         6        1.01     Fail
```

Basically it takes the max time, but it does not really print the correct data out, it prints the max time, but it prints the initial time of the whole unique group of data, instead of the initial time of that particular test (record).

I have tried so long to fix this, but I seem to be going no where. I have a feeling there is a join somewhere in here, but I tried that too, no luck.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the max ETime by FName and Ver, then join your main table to it:

```
SELECT
  NAMES.FName,
  NAMES.STime,
  NAMES.ETime,
  NAMES.Ver,
  NAMES.Rslt
FROM NAMES
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT FName, Ver, MAX(ETime) AS MaxETime
  FROM NAMES
  GROUP BY FName, Ver
) T ON NAMES.FName = T.FName AND NAMES.Ver = T.Ver AND NAMES.ETime = T.MaxETime
```

Comment: It worked when I added the tablename.column. Thank you so much, I was left joining the Etime to the Fnames and then right joining it to the versions, which didnt work. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that - I was looking at the forest and totally missed those trees :)  Someone (maybe you?) tried to fix my answer but for some reason it was rejected by community reviewers. I've updated the answer to include the mysteriously rejected edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could first find which is the latests=max(etime) for each case for each version  ?

```
select Fname,Ver,max(etime) from NAMES group by Fname,Ver;
```

From there you would display the whole thing via joining it again?

```
select * 
from 
  NAMES
inner join
  (select Fname,Ver,max(etime) as etime from NAMES group by Fname,Ver ) sub1
using (Fname,Ver,etime)
order by fname,Ver;
```